# Solving $\int_{-1}^{1} x \exp(xAx^T) dx$ and $\int_{-1}^{1} xx^T \exp(xAx^T) dx$

Tags: integration

Is it possible to provide an analytical solution for these two integrals:

(I) $\int_{-1}^{1} x \exp(xAx^T) dx$,

(II) $\int_{-1}^{1} xx^T \exp(xAx^T) dx$,

with $x\in R^D$. The matrix $A \in R^{D \times D}$ is symmetric. Not sure if this information is helpful.

Comment: If $x\in\Bbb{R}^d$, what does $\int_{-1}^1$ even mean? Specifically those bounds?

Comment: Sry for the shortened notation. Each dimension $x_i$ has the same bounds -1,1